# Breadcrumbs code fix long text

Tags: css

when i enter a long text in my breadcrumbs they break.. any ideas?

Feel free to Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/neodjandre/pbEpG/

```css
.breadsmall ul{margin:0px;}
.breadsmall ul li{display:inline-block;height:20px;line-height:20px;width:100px;text-indent:10px;text-align:center;position:relative;margin:5px 1px 0 0;}
.breadsmall ul li:before{content:" ";height:0;width:0;position:absolute;left:-2px;z-index:0;border-color:transparent transparent transparent #fff;border-style:solid;border-width:10px 0 10px 10px;}
.breadsmall ul li:first-child:before{border-color:transparent;}
.breadsmall ul li a:after{content:" ";height:0;width:0;position:absolute;right:-10px;z-index:10;border-color:transparent transparent transparent #e8e8e8;border-style:solid;border-width:10px 0 10px 10px;}
.breadsmall ul li a{display:block;background: #e8e8e8;font-family:Century Gothic, sans-serif;font-size:1em;color:#666666}
.breadsmall ul li a:hover{background:#1f1f1f;color:#eaeaea;}
.breadsmall ul li a:hover:after{border-color:transparent transparent transparent #1f1f1f;}
.breadsmall ul li.active a{background:#1f1f1f;z-index:100;color:#eaeaea;}
.breadsmall ul li.active a:after{border-left-color:#1f1f1f;}
```

Comment: could anyone please tell me how to paste code in stackoverflow... using firefox - i can't get to format it correctly no matter what i do.. :(

Comment: I use FireFox, and just use four spaces before each line of code, plus any indentation you want.

Comment: Highlight code, CTRL+K. I fixed it.

Comment: Alyce do i really need to put 4 spaces on each line of code?????

Comment: Doorknob - i would try this next time...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `min-width: 100px;` instead of `width: 100px;` for the `<li>`.

```
.breadsmall ul li {
    min-width: 100px;   
}
```

Looks like this: http://jsfiddle.net/MRSallee/pbEpG/1/

That match what you want?

Comment: yes although i wouldn't mind some more padding on the left and right of the long text! don't worry i figured it out .. thanks a lot :)